# How do I do the equivalent of Gimp's Colors, Auto, White Balance in Python-Fu?

Tags: python, scripting, gimp

the only function I can find is : gimp-color-balance, which takes the applicable parameters : preserve-lum(osity), cyan-red, magenta-green, and yellow-blue.

I'm not sure what values to pass for these parameters to duplicate the menu option in the title.

Comment: I was asking the same thing over on r/Gimp.  https://www.reddit.com/r/GIMP/comments/7qw7eb/how_do_you_call_automatic_white_balance_from_a/

Comment: Related: [Auto image enhance for Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/370920/auto-image-enhance-for-ubuntu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complete the answer of @banderlog013, I think the [Gimp Doc](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-layer-white-balance.html) specifies that the end pixels of each channel are first discarded, then the remaining ranges are stretched. I believe the right code is :

```
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
balanced_img = np.zeros_like(img) #Initialize final image

for i in range(3): #i stands for the channel index 
    hist, bins = np.histogram(img[..., i].ravel(), 256, (0, 256))
    bmin = np.min(np.where(hist>(hist.sum()*0.0005)))
    bmax = np.max(np.where(hist>(hist.sum()*0.0005)))
    balanced_img[...,i] = np.clip(img[...,i], bmin, bmax)
    balanced_img[...,i] = (balanced_img[...,i]-bmin) / (bmax - bmin) * 255
```

I obtain good results with it, try it out !

Comment: Don't forget to install opencv and call `import cv2` first too! See here for installation instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853018/how-do-i-install-opencv-using-pip/56315658#56315658.

Comment: Maybe I had edited my answer a long time ago, but my code works exactly as you stated

Answer (score 2):

According to [GIMP doc](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-layer-white-balance.html), we need to discard pixel colors at each end of the Red, Green and Blue histograms which are used by only 0.05% of the pixels in the image and stretch the remaining range as much as possible (**Python code**):

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2  # opencv-python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
x = []
# get histogram for each channel
for i in cv2.split(img):
    hist, bins = np.histogram(i, 256, (0, 256))
    # discard colors at each end of the histogram which are used by only 0.05% 
    tmp = np.where(hist > hist.sum() * 0.0005)[0]
    i_min = tmp.min()
    i_max = tmp.max()
    # stretch hist
    tmp = (i.astype(np.int32) - i_min) / (i_max - i_min) * 255
    tmp = np.clip(tmp, 0, 255)
    x.append(tmp.astype(np.uint8))

# combine image back and show it
s = np.dstack(x)
plt.imshow(s[::,::,::-1])
```

The result is pretty the same as after GIMP's 'Colors -> Auto -> White Balance'

**UPD:** we need `np.clip()` because `OpenCV` and `numpy` differently casts int32 to uint8:

```
# Numpy
np.array([-10, 260]).astype(np.uint8)
>>> array([246,   4], dtype=uint8)
# but we need just [0, 255]
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand after a quick look at the source code (and more or less confirmed with a test image), these are unrelated and under the hood,`Colors>Auto>White Balance`:

- obtains the histogram for each channel
- get the values that determine the bottom and top 0.6%
- stretches the range of values for that channel using these two values as the black and white points using an internal call that is very similar to "Levels".

Proof with a synthetic image:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

All this isn't hard to do in Python.

Comment: Since you posted a test image, you must have written code yourself in some language. Can you post it as a guideline for me to base the python code on please? I have limited experience with python.

Comment: The images I posted are just showing the effect of `Auto>White balance` on a test image. If you want example Gimp scripts in python, see [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) (`ofn-average-fill`  uses `gimp_histogram()`).  If you want a complete implementation see DoyourSketch2's answer. If you want a real white-balance script that does everything correctly, see [this](http://luca.dealfaro.org/photography/Whitebalance) but you have to specify a color in the image which should be neutral gray (ie R==G==B).

Answer (score 0):

### How to essentially get the equivalent of GIMP's `Colors --> Auto --> White Balance` feature:

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04.

Download the below code from my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo here: [python/auto_white_balance_img.py](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/python/auto_white_balance_img.py).

Install dependencies:

```sh
pip3 install opencv-python  # for cv2
pip3 install numpy
```

Now here is some fully-functional code, unlike some of the other answers here which are snippets and lacking things like `import` statements. I'm borrowing from [@Canette Ouverture's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56365560/4561887), and [@banderlog013's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54864315/4561887).

Create file **auto_white_balance_img.py**:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

file_in = 'test.jpg'

file_in_base = file_in[:-4] # strip file extension
file_in_extension = file_in[-4:]

img = cv2.imread(file_in)

# From @banderlog013's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54864315/4561887
x = []
# get histogram for each channel
for i in cv2.split(img):
    hist, bins = np.histogram(i, 256, (0, 256))
    # discard colors at each end of the histogram which are used by only 0.05%
    img_out1 = np.where(hist > hist.sum() * 0.0005)[0]
    i_min = img_out1.min()
    i_max = img_out1.max()
    # stretch hist
    img_out1 = (i.astype(np.int32) - i_min) / (i_max - i_min) * 255
    img_out1 = np.clip(img_out1, 0, 255)
    x.append(img_out1.astype(np.uint8))

# From @Canette Ouverture's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56365560/4561887
img_out2 = np.zeros_like(img) # Initialize final image
for channel_index in range(3):
    hist, bins = np.histogram(img[..., channel_index].ravel(), 256, (0, 256))
    bmin = np.min(np.where(hist>(hist.sum()*0.0005)))
    bmax = np.max(np.where(hist>(hist.sum()*0.0005)))
    img_out2[...,channel_index] = np.clip(img[...,channel_index], bmin, bmax)
    img_out2[...,channel_index] = ((img_out2[...,channel_index]-bmin) / 
        (bmax - bmin) * 255)

# Write new files
cv2.imwrite(file_in_base + '_out1' + file_in_extension, img_out1)
cv2.imwrite(file_in_base + '_out2' + file_in_extension, img_out2)
```

Make **auto_white_balance_img.py** executable:

```
chmod +x auto_white_balance_img.py
```

Now set the `file_in` variable in the file above to your desired input image path, then run it with:

```
python3 auto_white_balance_img.py
# OR
./auto_white_balance_img.py
```

Assuming you have set `file_in = 'test.jpg'`, it will produce these two files:

1. `test_out1.jpg` # The result from [@banderlog013's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54864315/4561887)
2. `test_out2.jpg` # The result from [@Canette Ouverture's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56365560/4561887)

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to auto white balance images. Unlike Gimp function, it does not normalize image contrast. So it is useful with low contrast images too.

```
import numpy as np
from imageio import imread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def auto_white_balance(im, p=.6):
    '''Stretch each channel histogram to same percentile as mean.'''

    # get mean values
    p0, p1 = np.percentile(im, p), np.percentile(im, 100-p)

    for i in range(3):
        ch = im[:,:,i]
        # get channel values
        pc0, pc1 = np.percentile(ch, p), np.percentile(ch, 100-p)
        # stretch channel to same range as mean
        ch = (p1 - p0) * (ch - pc0) / (pc1 - pc0) + p0
        im[:,:,i] = ch
        
    return im

def test():

    im = imread('imageio:astronaut.png')
    # distort white balance
    im[:,:,0] = im[:,:,0] *.6
    im[:,:,1] = im[:,:,1] *.8

    plt.imshow(im)
    plt.show()

    im2 = auto_white_balance(im)
    im2 = np.clip(im2, 0, 255)  # or 0, 1 for float images

    plt.imshow(im2)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

If you want equivalent of Gimp function, use fixed values instead:
p0, p1 = 0, 255

Answer (score -2):

K, cool.  Figured out how to script one up.
Use it if you like.  Does alright by me.

https://github.com/doyousketch2/eAWB

[image: pic]

Comment: I figured out, you wrote :)

Comment: Your "answer" didn't tell me anything I didn't already know.  It was more of a non-answer, really.  Just because you put pictures up didn't explain anything new.  I knew how GIMP achieved those values.  My question was: is there a function to call it.  Apparently there wasn't.  You basically said write it yourself.  So I did.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/GIMP/comments/7qw7eb/how_do_you_call_automatic_white_balance_from_a/

Comment: You're only proving my point.  My question was: "What function calls Automatic White Balance??"  I think you are confusing me with the poster of this question instead.