# How do I install opencv using pip?

Tags: python, opencv

I need to install `cv2` for a script that has been written for me. I tried  `pip install cv2` and `pip install open_cv` and got the same problem - a warning message from `dist.py` and complains about `zlib` being not found. No cv2 installed. I also tried `pyopenvc` and `pip install opencv-python`.

So, I went to the opencv site and downloaded the relevant exe. Ran it - generated a heap of subdirectories and a make file and stuff.

What do I do now?

Answer (score 350):

Install [`opencv-python`](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) (which is the **official** pre-built OpenCV package for Python) by issuing the following command:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: Follow up question, what is the correct way to determine the PIP name of a library?

Comment: @MrDysprosium Refer to the library documentation.

Comment: The superior answer would be to pick opencv-contrib-python as the package of preference to install.

Comment: @MrDysprosium if you know the name used to import it but not the name to install it (which, stupidly, is often different) then you have to use PyPi's website or a search engine etc, because pip no longer supports search

Answer (score 70):

run the following command by creating a virtual enviroment using python 3 and run

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

to check it has installed correctly run

```
python3 -c "import cv2"
```

Answer (score 56):

In `pip` package management, there are 4 different OpenCV packages all using the same namespace, `cv2`. Although they are not officially supported by [OpenCV.org](https://opencv.org/), they are commonly used in developers' community. You could install any of them using the following command:

```
pip install PACKAGE_NAME
```

where `PACKAGE_NAME` can be

- `opencv-python`  (only contains main modules)
- `opencv-contrib-python` (contains both main and contrib modules)
- `opencv-python-headless` (same as `opencv-python` but without GUI functionality)
- `opencv-contrib-python-headless` (same as `opencv-contrib-python` but without GUI functionality)

You should only install one of them depending on your needs. If you accidentally installed multiple of them in the same environment, you can remove them using `pip uninstall` before installing the correct one again.

For more details, you can refer to the project description of [OpenCV on Wheels.](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/)

As of 2021, all of these 4 packages are official OpenCV projects. Source: [OpenCV Website.](https://opencv.org/opencv-python-is-now-an-official-opencv-project/)

Answer (score 14):

#### To Install the Current Latest version of OpenCV then use the below commands:

**Use this Command:**

```
pip install --upgrade opencv-python
```

**If you're facing problem in above command then try this :**

```
pip install --upgrade opencv-contrib-python
```

**To check the version of installed OpenCV:**

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
```

Comment: `--upgrade` helped

Comment: You install one or the other... not both.

Answer (score 10):

Simply use this for the so far latest version 4.1.0.

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.1.0.25
```

For the default version use this:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

If you have a new Raspberry Pi and want to install OpenCV then this [tutorial](https://pyshine.com/How-to-install-OpenCV-in-Rasspberry-Pi/) would be a good choice.

For Ubuntu/Linux users:

```
sudo apt install python3-opencv
```

Answer (score 8):

As of 10/22/2019, I think the best answer is simply

```
conda install opencv
```

It appears `opencv` is now in the main `Anaconda` channel.

To see which packages (including `opencv`) are in the main `Anaconda` channel go to [Anaconda Package Lists](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs/) and follow the link corresponding to your python version and os version.

Answer (score 6):

Everybody struggles initially while installing OpenCV. OpenCV requires a lot of dependencies in the backend. The best way to start with OpenCV is, install it in a virtual environment. I suggest that you use the Python Anaconda distribution and create a virtual environment using it. Then inside the virtual environment, you can install OpenCV using this command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

Comment: While I do agree with the suggestion to use Conda, that particular package has been unmaintained for **more than three years**!

Answer (score 6):

Please follow the command:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

then if you want to use:

```
import cv2
```

If it's not worked due to any update, please follow the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)

Answer (score 4):

You can install opencv the normal way:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

If you are getting errors, you can do this:

```
pip install opencv-python-headless
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a virtual enviroment using python3

```
virtualenv env_name --python="python3"
```

and run the following command

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

to check it has installed correctly run

```
python3 -c "import cv2"
```

Answer (score 3):

To install open_cv you can go to [this](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/install-opencv-3-for-python-on-windows/) website or do this,

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python --upgrade
pip install opencv-python
```

You can test it by:

```
C:\> python
>>> import cv2
>>> print(cv2.__version__)
'4.5.1' # your version may be a newer one
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Open anaconda command prompt and type in below command.

   `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`
2. Once the 'Solving environment' is done. It will ask to download dependencies. Type 'y'.
3. It will install all the dependencies and then you are ready to code.

Comment: This works, but this doesn't answer the question which asks for a solution that uses pip

Answer (score 2):

I recommend this for Python 3: Please install it this way with pip

```sh
pip3 install opencv-python
```

This will download and install the latest version of OpenCV.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using below command-

**pip install opencv-contrib-python**

It will basically download the compatible version. If this command fails, you could upgrade you pip using below command-

**python -m pip install –upgrade pip**

If you need a pictorial guide, head over to [Simple Steps to Install OpenCV in Windows](https://techyeverything.com/install-pip-python-tensorflow-opencv-in-windows-easily/)

You can also try installing OpenCV from prebuilt binaries from the official [OpenCV site.](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html)

Answer (score 2):

As a reference it might help someone... On Debian system I hard to do the following:

```
apt-get install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev
pip3 install opencv-python
python3 -c "import cv2"
```

Answer (score 2):

->pip install opencv-python you can use this.

But if this code does not working then you can check python version on cmd and anaconda because they are different. So you type command in anaconda prompt and cmd, it will work. You can check this -> pip list

Answer (score 1):

1. Open terminal
2. Run the following command
   `pip install --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org opencv-python`.
3. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu you can install it for the system Python with

```
sudo apt install python3-opencv
```

Answer (score 1):

**Installing cv2 or opencv-python using pip is sometimes a problem.** I was having the same problem of installing cv2 with pip. The installation wasn't a problem the problem was to import cv2 after installation. I was getting an **Import Error** so to fix this i import main from pip to install opencv-python. Try to run the following code in your python file then **opencv-python** will be installed

```
from pip._internal import main as install
try:
    import cv2
except ImportError as e:
    install(["install", "opencv-python"])
finally:
    pass
```

**I hope this will help someone**

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Pycharm navigate settings > Project:name > Project interpreter just search the module by name(in this case OpenCV-python) and install it. worked for me

Comment: How that actually installs the library depends on which package management tool you're using, and this can be done from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

### In case you use **aarch64** platform with ARM64 cpu - and/or docker

On a development board on ARM64, no python-opencv version were found at all

`version: NONE`.
I've had to build from source. This allowed to include CUDA support.

In my case it was already available on the board but it wasn't found on the development environment.

If compiling from source is out of reach, there are [Dockers](https://github.com/loitho/docker-opencv-cuda)

Of course compiling will take some time (few hours on ARM core), but it is worthy process to know as most open source tools can be built this way in case of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Recent answer from Aug, 2023

https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/#description

Note: The pip package is maintained by OpenCV

As mentioned in the official documentation:

a. Packages for standard desktop environments (Windows, macOS, almost any GNU/Linux distribution)

Option 1 - Main modules package: pip install opencv-python

Option 2 - Full package (contains both main modules and contrib/extra modules): pip install opencv-contrib-python (check contrib/extra modules listing from OpenCV documentation)

Do not install both since this might lead to conflicts!

Answer (score -1):

I've had this problem in **Google Colab**, It only worked with this specific package version.

```
!pip install "opencv-python-headless<4.3"
```

Answer (score -5):

There are two options-

```
pip install cv2
```

or

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Hope it helps.