# How can I use cv2.face and cv2 with creating a window by using QT, without getting errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, opencv

I want to use openCV, but with different openCV versions I get different errors.

For e.g when I use `pip install opencv-python-headless` code something like:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg', -1)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(5000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

works fine. But when I want to use the `face` attribute, it crashes with the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create())
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'
```

To fix the issue, I need to install openCV by using `sudo python3 -m pip install opencv-contrib-python`. But if I now execute the script above, the error

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

appears.

So how can I avoid both errors?

**EDIT:**
With the normal installation `pip install opencv-python` both errors appear. So it can not find the `face` attribute and is not able to create a window by using `QT`

Comment: the question is duplicated, the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853018/how-do-i-install-opencv-using-pip can give you an answer.

Comment: No cause when I use the normal way to install it, I get in both cases the error.

Comment: Why is it a bad question? Both problems are rarely answered on stackoverflow and github with a bad solution. And this particular problem was not asked on any platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the latest opencv-python version is broken, so I just need to `pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.1.0.25`