# ImportError: cannot import name 'dnn_superres' for python example of super resolution with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network, opencv-contrib

I am trying to run an example for upscaling images from the following website:
https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-based-super-resolution-with-opencv-4fd736678066

This is the code I am using:

```
import cv2
from cv2 import dnn_superres

# Create an SR object
sr = dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()

# Read image
image = cv2.imread('butterfly.png')

# Read the desired model
path = "EDSR_x3.pb"
sr.readModel(path)

# Set the desired model and scale to get correct pre- and post-processing
sr.setModel("edsr", 3)

# Upscale the image
result = sr.upsample(image)

# Save the image
cv2.imwrite("./upscaled.png", result)
```

I have downloaded the already trained model from the website, called "EDSR_x3.pb" and when I run the code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upscale.py", line 2, in <module>
    from cv2 import dnn_superres
ImportError: cannot import name 'dnn_superres'
```

I now it seems like there is no such method or class, but I have already installed opencv and the contrib modules. Why do I get this error?

Comment: What `opencv` version do you have?

Comment: Python 3.7.4
Opencv 4.2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem with Python 3.6.9 and opencv 4.2.0, but after the upgrade to 4.3.0, the problem disappeared. If you have no problem upgrading the version, try 4.3.0.

Comment: opencv 4.3.0 cannot be installed through pip as it is not yet available

Answer (score 19):

The key is in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/) for opencv-python. dnn_superres is an extra module and requires you to install opencv-contrib-python

`pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Answer (score 8):

your opencv version should be opencv4.2.0+, the same question:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/2544

solution:

```sh
pip install --upgrade opencv-python
pip install --upgrade opencv-contrib-python
```

Answer (score 5):

*As of this date, to add something to the currently accepted answer :*

**If you are doing it in your local system :**

If you have

> opencv-python

you need to uninstall it first, you can check if you have above package or not by the command :

`pip show opencv-python`

if you have it, uninstall it first by

`pip uninstall opencv-python`

and install

> opencv-contrib-python

by

`pip install opencv-contrib-python`

by default it will download the latest version but still check the version by the *show* command above for *opencv-contrib-python* this time, just to check the version is above opencv4.2.0+, to force download a speicific version go through this : [pip install package_name==version_number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51853018/5963608)

**If you are doing it in Google Colab :**

*opencv-python* is already installed in colab but the version is *4.1.2*, you can check it by :

```
import cv2
cv2.__version__
```

you don't need to uninstall it, you just need to install *opencv-contrib-python* but if you install  by :

`!pip install opencv-contrib-python`

It won't install it, it would default to same preinstalled opencv

so run this :

`!pip install opencv-contrib-python==`

which will output all the available versions for colab, just select any version 4.3.x or above and run again, like:

`!pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.3.0.36`

Comment: This did it for me after uninstalling both and only reinstalling `opencv-contrib-python`.

Answer (score 3):

Run the below commands into your terminal

```
pip install --upgrade opencv-contrib-python
pip install --upgrade opencv-python
```

Then, Restart your Jupyter notebok kernel or Reactivate your virtual environment so that the updated package can be used properly.