# module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'dnn_superres'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to upscale image (performing super resolution) using OpenCV, but I am getting this error that module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'dnn_superres'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using 4.4.0.44 OpenCV version. Here is the code section.

```
import cv2
sr = cv2.dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()
sr.readModel(args["model"])
sr.setModel(modelName, modelScale)
```

Comment: Did you look at this [-cannot-import-name-dnn-superres-for-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61159469/importerror-cannot-import-name-dnn-superres-for-python-example-of-super-resol)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In case you are using python3, you need to download opencv with pip3

First uninstall opencv:

```
 pip uninstall opencv-python
 pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
```

Then install latest version of opencv with pip3:

```
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
```

Comment: or you just don't have opencv-contrib-python and need to install it without deleting anything