# How to install Opencv in python (Repl.it)

Tags: python, opencv, replit

Fairly new to coding.  All suggestions say to input pip install opencv-python but this gives syntax error "invalid syntax".  I don''t understand at all. Any help is appreciated

I tried what everyone said to do. Expected it to work.

Comment: Where are you running the pip install command? its meant for the terminal, sounds like you are running it inside a python interpreter (that will not work).

Comment: Yes I am using a pyton interpreter. Should I not be using this? and where is the terminal? What program do you use for python??

Comment: I found the terminal. Hooray! Thank you!!

Comment: Please view this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853018/how-do-i-install-opencv-using-pip